# My app crashes when trying to parse a string which only has numbers into an integer. How do I solve this problem?

Tags: java, android, string-parsing

The below is the code I used in my app. The input type for the EditText is number. I receive the data entered into a String variable called 'name'. I try to parse it into an integer variable and this is where I believe that code crashes.

'''

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String name;
    int num;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        final TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        final EditText edtxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxt1);//input type is number
        final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                name = edtxt1.getText().toString();
                num = Integer.parseInt(name);
                txt1.setText(num);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

You have to set String not Int. Change like this

```
txt1.setText(num.toString());
```

Comment: are you saying that i cant print numbers on a TextView?